# Make C# user.config not version dependent

Tags: c#, app-config

My C# project uses the default config thing (`Properties > Settings.settings`), which stores a config file in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\MyApp\MyApp.exe_Url_hashorsomething`. How can I do the same without that last directory, or so that last directory does not depend on the exe name and hash (or whatever that part is).

Also, how would I make it store it in Roaming instead of Local?

Comment: Will dig out the code I used to migrate settings to a newer version of the app. 2 mins.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find that question while searching. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than getting rid of the "hash or something", I did this by adding a string property `CurrentVersion` to the settings. Then on startup, I can call the following method:

```
public static void UpgradeSettingsIfRequired()
{
    string version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    if (Settings.Default.CurrentVersion != version)
    {
        Settings.Default.Upgrade();
        Settings.Default.CurrentVersion = version;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Don't know how you'd go about moving them to the roaming profile though. Sorry.